# Rails 3 Custom Method Location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am currently trying to add some parsing methods to a controller method in a Rails 3 application.

I have a controller action as follows:

```
def control
  @device = Device.find(params[:id])
  <do things>
  parse_return(@returned_data)
end
```

and I added a custom method to the controller as below (this method would not have any routes and would only be accessible to controller actions):

```
def parse_return
  <parse data>
end
```

but this does not appear to allow the parse_return method to be used. Is there somewhere else in the Rails app that I can put re-usable methods?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a first glance it seems that you fail to render a response. Is it true that `control` action doesn't have an associated view?

In this case you have to manually call `render` in your action. For example, to render JSON response you can do this:

```
def control
  # ...

  render :json => parse_return(@returned_data),
         :content_type => 'application/json',
         :layout => false
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should include what the errors are.

What happens if you try this?

```
def parse_return(returned_data)
  <parse data>
end
```

Perhaps the method is not expecting an parameter to be passed along with it.

Comment: Also, you may also put methods inside models and call them from the controller, if you wish.